# PHP mysqli Prepared Statement with anonymous join

Tags: php, mysql, join, mysqli, prepared-statement

I am currently frustrated with preparing one statement - culprit is not preparing it properly, but staying inline with my current function to bin a query with a variable number of parameters. It works in all cases, but this query gives me an unsolveable problem (in one single query) for mysql:

```
SELECT studios.name,
        studios.phone,
        locations.zip_code,
        locations.location_name,
        addresses.street_name,
        addresses.stree_nr,
        persons.first_name,
        persons.last_name,
        p.distance_unit
            * DEGREES(ACOS(COS(RADIANS(p.latpoint))
            * COS(RADIANS(addresses.geo_lat))
            * COS(RADIANS(p.longpoint) - RADIANS(addresses.geo_long ))
            + SIN(RADIANS(p.latpoint))
            * SIN(RADIANS(addresses.geo_lat)))) AS distance
FROM    studios
JOIN    (   /* these are the query parameters */
          SELECT  ? AS latpoint, ? AS longpoint,
                  ? AS radius,   111.045 AS distance_unit
        ) AS p ON 1=1
CROSS JOIN  addresses
ON          studios.address = addresses.id
CROSS JOIN  locations
ON          addresses.location = locations.id
CROSS JOIN  persons
ON          studios.owner = persons.id
CROSS JOIN  studio_types
ON          studios.studio_type = studio_types.id
WHERE       addresses.geo_lat
    BETWEEN p.latpoint  - (p.radius / p.distance_unit)
        AND p.latpoint  + (p.radius / p.distance_unit)
        AND addresses.geo_long
    BETWEEN p.longpoint - (p.radius / (p.distance_unit * COS(RADIANS(p.latpoint))))
        AND p.longpoint + (p.radius / (p.distance_unit * COS(RADIANS(p.latpoint))))
ORDER BY    distance
LIMIT 25
```

The query itself is fully functional - here is a gist of it:

```
SELECT *
FROM    studios
JOIN    ( SELECT  ? AS latpoint, ? AS longpoint,
                  ? AS radius,   111.045 AS distance_unit
        ) AS p ON 1=1
```

now binding it is pretty straight forward:

```
$query = $this->conn->prepare($query);
if(!$query) throw new Exception($this->conn->error);
$query->bind_params("ddd", $val1, $val2, $val2);
$query->execute();
$query->get_result();
```

The error that occures by preparing already happens in the first line: `Unknown column 'p.latpoint' in 'field list'`

Now this is a huge problem. Going around that would probably work with preparing statements with `SET @variable = ?` - but thats not a preferred situation, as it would break up my current scheme of dispatching my requests.

Is there any oversight or is this simply not possible, due to undefined joins while preparing?

Edit: third method would involve replacing the join and placing values - this would make a very confusuing amount of bind parameters - which would be hard to maintain later.

Comment: The [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) states that placeholders cannot be used for identifiers (including columns).

Comment: Gotcha - so either use multiple prepares (which potentially fails if I use the result before binding) - or replacing the join with a long list of parameters.

Answer (score 0):

So, I finally come around for anyone who seeks the same answer like me and I gotta extend where I left with it:

Imagine a class that does all the heavy lifting for you, minimizing issues provides you a simple interface between you and your database. There is a method that takes a statement string, type binding and like this:

```
protected function __dispatch($query, $types, $arguments) {
    error_reporting(0);
    $query = $this->conn->prepare($query);
    if(!$query) throw new Exception($this->conn->error);
    if($types !== "") call_user_func_array(array(&$query, 'bind_param'),
                                           array_merge(array($types), $arguments));
    $query->execute();
    return $query->get_result();
}
```

Since placeholders cannot possibly any identifiers (thanks Jon), I can however bind SQL variables just fine. Then I am going to execute something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM    studios
JOIN    ( SELECT  @lat AS latpoint, @lon AS longpoint,
                  @dist AS radius,   111.045 AS distance_unit
        ) AS p ON 1=1
```

This gives the possibility to bind variables before - and then use it in the statement, just like this:

```
public function search_in_range($lat, $long, $distance) {
    $this->__dispatch("SET @lat = ?", "d", array(&$lat));
    $this->__dispatch("SET @lon = ?", "d", array(&$long));
    $this->__dispatch("SET @dist = ?", "d", array(&$distance));
    // And finally:
    return $this->__dispatch($query, $types, [])->fetch_all();
}
```

This does the trick to create to have a very simple join with an anonymous set of data and use it in a more complicated statement later on.